# What is Fault Tolerant Write？

Tags: uefi

Inspect UEFI code recently, one of the modules is FaultTolerantWritePei.inf, never understand this knowledge.

I tried using a search engine, but I didn't find anything particularly correct and specific.

Comment: A `.inf` file is a Microsoft-style driver file that tells windows how to set up a particular type of hardware device.  Can you link to the place where you saw this particular file so we can know exactly what you're asking about?

Comment: Look at the source code file `...\FaultTolerantWriteDxe/FaultTolerantWrite.c` for the specific details.

Comment: I am going to ask the source code through the knowledge content.